# Facebook Paper - what 3rd party libraries are used for what parts of the app?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, facebook, animation

**I just download [Facebook Paper](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/paper-stories-from-facebook/id794163692) app for iOS.** There's a lot of great stuff in this app, specifically animation wise. It runs smooth as butter for me too - some really great stuff going on behind the scenes evidently.

**What I'd like to know** is what libraries are used for which features of the app (3rd parties libraries used are listed below. There's a truckload of them). Basically, how did they get it looking and working as well as it does - which of these libraries can I use to do the same?

Since this is a pretty broad question, specifically I'd like to know about animations - fold, swipe down, tap on a settings section, tap an icon. Was a third party library used - how did Facebook achieve the smoothness and complexity of animations that are there?

All 3rd party libraries from Facebook paper are listed below.

> ```
> ACE 
> Appirater
> Reachability
> AQGridView
> bitvect
> Boost
> Breadcrumb
> breakpad
> Chromium
> CocoaHTTPServer
> CocoaLumberjack
> DCRoundSwitch
> DTCoreText
> EGODatabase
> expat
> FFT by Mark Oleson
> FFT by Takuya Ooura
> gh-kit
> gh-unit
> Google Toolbox for Mac
> google-web-toolkit
> gtest
> gyp
> IEEE 754r Half Precision floating...
> HPGrowingTextView
> InAppSettingsKit
> ios5-cookbook
> ios-8601-parser-unparser
> jqueryjs
> JSONKit
> leveldb
> LibComponentLogging-Core
> LibComponentLogging-NSLog
> libjingle
> libjpeg-turbo
> libjpeg
> libPhoneNumber-iOS
> libphonenumber
> libsrtp
> libvpx
> libyuv
> llvmreturn
> MAZeroingWeakRef
> minizip
> mizpanel-iphone
> mosquitto
> MessagePack Objective C Imple...
> MessagePack
> msinttypes
> OpenCV Tutorials
> nimbus
> NJKWebViewProgress
> unmodified objc4
> ObjQREncoder
> OCHamcrest
> OCMock
> OCPDFGen
> OmniGroup OmniUI
> OpenSSL
> OpenUDID
> opus
> peertalk
> PhotoScroller
> PHP
> PLCrashReporter
> pmtk3
> Pocket-ObjC-SDK
> portaudio
> protobuf
> PSTCollectionView
> SUtilities
> RestKit
> Ring Buffer Utility
> SDURLCache
> SDWebImage
> SOCKit
> SPDY-for-iPhone
> spdylay
> spreadsort
> ssziparchive
> TDOauth
> tiqr
> UAModalPanel
> webkit
> webp
> webrtc
> WebViewJavascriptBridge
> XMLReader
> yaml-cpp
> yasm
> zlib
> zxing
> ```

Comment: Facebook just release the library that they use.
https://github.com/facebook/pop

Comment: How did you get that list?

Answer (score 10):

**Quote from an engineer working on paper:**

> The engineering complexity here is finding a way to fully utilize the
>   multicore architecture of newer iPhones on top of the UIKit framework
>   which has no support for multithreading. Significant work went into
>   creating a framework for doing rendering work on multiple threads, and
>   we spent a long time finding the balance between performance and
>   complexity.

Full length article here: http://www.quora.com/Facebook-Launches-Paper-January-2014/What-was-it-like-to-help-develop-Paper/answer/Jason-Barrett-Prado?srid=iaDC&share=1

Answer (score 6):

Facebook held an event in San Francisco on 1st April called ["An Inside Look at Facebook Paper"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OiY1cheLpmI). See the section "Spring & Delight: Beyond Static Animations - Kimon Tsinteris".

In summary, for animations they used an in-house library called [Pop](https://github.com/facebook/pop) that has now been open-sourced. It's benefits over CoreAnimation are 1) that it doesn't depend on CALayer... any object can be animated 2) animations can be stopped mid-flow, and a new one started with the end state of the animated object matching where it was stopped. You will notice that animations in Paper can all be interrupted.

At F8 Facebook [announced](http://techcrunch.com/2014/04/30/facebook-will-soon-open-source-more-of-the-core-technology-behind-its-paper-app/) they would be open sourcing the rendering library DisplayNode that allows a large amount of rendering to happen off the main thread. This was released as [AsyncDisplayKit](https://github.com/facebook/AsyncDisplayKit) in October 2014.